# C++ std::set with a comparator that is time based?

Tags: c++, comparator

Is it bad for Comparators used in a C++ std::set to depend on time? i.e. Comparators that will return one thing at one time, but may return another result at a different time even for the exact same objects?

I've read that std::sets are weakly ordered with the comparator given. **Maybe there a way to do a refresh of the ordering right before getting the `mySet.begin()` or `myset.end()` values?**

As an example of a comparator that could change with time, think about Events and wanting to prioritize events that are closer to the current time:

```
class Event {
public:
    int64_t nTime;
}

class EventComparator {
    // pa < pb
    bool operator()(Event* pa, Event* pb) {
        int64_t now = GetTime();
        return (std::abs(pa->nTime - now) > std::abs(pb->nTime - now));
    }
}
```

Maybe there is a better way to sort events by time? Obviously, I could just do a vector and loop through to find the largest event, but just figured it would be good to use built in slot for a comparator.

Comment: Just use some kind of FIFO container. You don't really need the time, you just need a relative order.

Comment: No, that wouldn't be good. That would lead to outright undefined behaviour.

Comment: Thanks @Conduit, I was worried something like that might happen. What sort of a data structure would you suggest for this sort of thing? Also, if you post as an answer then I can mark it.

Comment: My comments have been moved into my answer.

Comment: Sets require a [strict weak ordering](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html). What you're describing doesn't fulfill that.

Comment: As per answer, your example does not make much sense because you can obtain the same behavior without subtracting the current time.

Comment: If you want a comparator that sorts based on proximity to the 'current' time, the way to implement that is to set what the 'current' time is up front and not change it. You wouldn't call `GetTime()` inside every comparison. Later when some time passes and you need a new sorting, you would create a new collection with an updated 'current' time and move the elements over, causing them to be resorted in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the relative order of elements within a `std::set` ever changes, the result is undefined behavior.

In your case, so long as things never happen in the future, and time never overflows, the `-now` is pointless.  If things happen both before and after the current time at any point, your code will exhibit undefined behavior.

If you simply sorted everything by their time, and then looked for elements **near** now, and processed from there, you'd get a similar result but no undefined behavior.

Ie, have a map from `int64_t` to `Event*`.  Store the time stamp in the `int64_t` (this makes some things easier).  Then get `lower_bound` of the current time, and carefully examine around it to find the even "nearest" to now (or any window you choose).

You can do this with a `std::set` if your compiler supports transparent comparators (a C++14 feature).  Simply implement a transparent comparator between `Event*` and `int64_t` timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

C++ gurus correct me if I am mistaken:

I believe that the comparator used by `std::set` instances orders the elements contained in the set within the underlying container. This is necessary to minimize the complexity of the operations and functions defined by `std::set`. Since the set relies on this ordering, having an order that changes is extremely ill-advised - it would cause intermittent (order might still be correct sometimes), undefined behavior in set functions relying on the proper ordering of the set's elements.

Hazarding a guess without seeing your code, I would say that [`std::list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/) or [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) would probably be more appropriate for your application. Check the complexity of the operations and functions you will be using, and make sure that all of them are present on the chosen container. You may need to fall back on the [`std::algorithm`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) class for assistance with some tasks, but try to stick to the container's built-in functionality if possible.

Answer (score 2):

I generally agree with what [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27829185/1392132) and [Conduit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27829126/1392132) have said: Don't make your comparator depend on global state, seriously.  To support this with even more authority, item 87 in *C++ Coding Standards* by Herb Sutter and Andrei Alexandrescu says:

> **Make predicates pure functions.**
>
> Predicate purity: A predicate is a function object that returns a yes / no answer, typically as a `bool` value.  A function is pure in a mathematical sense if its result depends only on its arguments (note that this use of “pure” has nothing to do with pure virtual functions).
>
> Don't allow predicates to hold or access state that affects the result of their `operator()`, including both member and global state.  Prefer to make `operator()` a `const` member function for predicates.

What I would most importantly like to add to the discussion is a simple solution to achieve multiple orderings that should be preferred in my opinion.

1. Store all elements (of type `Foo`) in a `std::vector<Foo>` using an arbitrary ordering that never changes.  The obvious choice is of course to simply `push_back()` them as they occur.
2. For each ordering you wish to use, define a pure ordering functor `Compare` with an `bool operator()(const Foo *, const Foo *) const;` and a corresponding `std::set<Foo *, Compare>` (using the constructor that accepts two iterators and a comparator) that is a lightweight structure of pointers into the vector.
3. If an ordering becomes obsolete, simply dispose of the corresponding set.

This approach is only worthwhile if you intend to access each ordering multiple (on the order of the number of elements) times.  If you merely wish to look up a small number of elements for various orderings, consider using [`std::partial_sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort) or [`std::partial_sort_copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partial_sort_copy) instead.  Consider sorting `std::vector<Foo *>` of pointers that are cheap to copy instead of your original `Foo` objects.

And now for some code:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

using Foo = std::pair<float, float>;
using FooIter = std::vector<Foo>::iterator;

std::ostream&
operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Foo& foo)
{
  os << std::fixed << std::setprecision(4)
     << "["
     << std::setw(8) << foo.first
     << ", "
     << std::setw(8) << foo.second
     << "]";
  return os;
}

// Ugly template, irrelevant for this discussin, don't use in production code.
template<typename ContainerT>
void
print_container(const ContainerT& container, const std::string& name)
{
  std::cout << name << "\n\n";
  for (const auto& it : container)
    std::cout << *it << "\n";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int
main()
{
  // Create a vector of 10 'Foo's.
  std::vector<Foo> items {};
  for (float x = 0.0f; x < 10.0f; x += 1.0f)
    items.emplace_back(x, std::sin(x));
  // For convenience, also create a vector of iterators into that vector.
  std::vector<FooIter> item_iterators {};
  for (auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ++it)
    item_iterators.push_back(it);
  // Comparator based on the first element.
  const auto cmp1 = [](const FooIter it1, const FooIter it2)->bool{
    return it1->first < it2->first;
  };
  // Comparator based on the second element.
  const auto cmp2 = [](const FooIter it1, const FooIter it2)->bool{
    return it1->second < it2->second;
  };
  {
    // Create a set ordered by the value of the first element.
    std::set<FooIter, decltype(cmp1)> set1 {
      item_iterators.begin(), item_iterators.end(), cmp1
    };
    print_container(set1, "set1");
  }
  {
    // Create a set ordered by the value of the second element.
    std::set<FooIter, decltype(cmp2)> set2 {
      item_iterators.begin(), item_iterators.end(), cmp2
    };
    print_container(set2, "set2");
  }
  {
    // Create a vector of the three smallest (by the first element) values.
    std::vector<FooIter> vec1(3);
    std::partial_sort_copy(item_iterators.begin(), item_iterators.end(),
                           vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), cmp1);
    print_container(vec1, "vec1");
  }
  {
    // Create a vector of the three smallest (by the second element) values.
    std::vector<FooIter> vec2(3);
    std::partial_sort_copy(item_iterators.begin(), item_iterators.end(),
                           vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), cmp2);
    print_container(vec2, "vec2");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
set1

[  0.0000,   0.0000]
[  1.0000,   0.8415]
[  2.0000,   0.9093]
[  3.0000,   0.1411]
[  4.0000,  -0.7568]
[  5.0000,  -0.9589]
[  6.0000,  -0.2794]
[  7.0000,   0.6570]
[  8.0000,   0.9894]
[  9.0000,   0.4121]

set2

[  5.0000,  -0.9589]
[  4.0000,  -0.7568]
[  6.0000,  -0.2794]
[  0.0000,   0.0000]
[  3.0000,   0.1411]
[  9.0000,   0.4121]
[  7.0000,   0.6570]
[  1.0000,   0.8415]
[  2.0000,   0.9093]
[  8.0000,   0.9894]

vec1

[  0.0000,   0.0000]
[  1.0000,   0.8415]
[  2.0000,   0.9093]

vec2

[  5.0000,  -0.9589]
[  4.0000,  -0.7568]
[  6.0000,  -0.2794]
```